# Add X row with textboxes in Repeater based on input number ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to bind x rows on repeater when user enters a number in a textbox. There will be 3 textboxes per row. This is what i have managed so far.

Here I add ID to textboxes

```
protected void rptComponentes_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(txtNumComponentes.Text); i++)
            {
                Label lblIdComponente = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblIdComponente");                  
                lblIdComponente.ID += (i + 1);
                TextBox txtComponente = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtComponente");        
                txtComponente.ID += (i + 1);
                TextBox txtBase = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtBase");  
                txtBase.ID += (i + 1);
                TextBox txtComprimento = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtComprimento");  
                txtComprimento.ID += (i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is supposed to add a row but nothing appears. I'm still very bad with making a datatable by hand.

```
  protected void BindComponentes()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;

        //define the columns
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(double)));
        //create new row
        dr = dt.NewRow();

        //add the row to DataTable
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        rptComponentes.DataSource = dt;
        rptComponentes.DataBind();
    }
```

This is the repeater

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="rptComponentes" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptComponentes_OnItemDataBound">
      <HeaderTemplate>
          <table id="tblArtigos" class="table table-bordered dataTable text-center">
              <thead class="thead-dark">
                 <tr>
                     <th>#</th>
                     <th>Componente *</th>
                     <th>Base *</th>
                     <th>Comprimento *</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <tbody>
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     <asp:Label ID="lblIdComponente" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm rounded border border-dark" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtComponente" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm rounded border border-dark" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtBase" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm rounded border border-dark" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtComprimento" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm rounded border border-dark" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate>
          </table>
      </FooterTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

EDIT:
It seems the problem is when I give ID to the dynamic textboxes, I get null exception

Comment: Try moving `<tbody>` in `HeaderTemplate` and `</tbody>` in `FooterTemplate`

Comment: They appear now but it seems not the right number of rows because i get nullexception when I'm giving ID's on databound event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

Add N number of rows to the datable based on the integer value input into txtNumComponentes

```
  protected void BindComponentes()
    {
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(txtNumComponentes.Text); i++)
        {

            DataRow dr = null;

              dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(double)));
        //create new row
        dr = dt.NewRow();

        //add the row to DataTable
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

       rptComponentes.DataSource = dt;
        rptComponentes.DataBind();
}
```

Then update ItemDataBound eventhandler code:

```
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {

             int itemIndex =  e.Item.ItemIndex;
             Label lblIdComponente = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblIdComponente");                  
                lblIdComponente.ID = itemIndex.ToString();

            // Similar logic for other control IDs
        }
```

Comment: Ah this is it! I couldn't figure out how to loop through the controls to ID them. I forgot about the index of the eventhandler... Thanks a lot!